# My NSArrayController content is changed even if it is readonly?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My NSArrayController is readonly

```
@property (readonly) NSArrayController *rootObjectsArrayController;
```

but its content is changed anyway

```
[[aClass rootObjectsArrayController] setContent:contentArray];
```

and it works. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read only for a property definition just means that you can't set that property - e.g you can't set a *new* array controller as the rootObjectsArrayController via generated accessor methods.

There is nothing stopping you modifying the object that is returned from the getter, though. This would be the same if you had a mutable array as a read only property- you could add objects to the array after accessing it via the property.

Answer (score 1):

Property with attribute `readonly` means that only the `read` accessor will be generated (synthesized) so no setter like `setRootObjectsArrayController`, it does not mean that the object will be readonly.

That's why you can still pass a message to it.

See [Apple's ObjectiveC ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to look at this, but the way that works for me is this:

A property that is readonly means that you cannot assign another object to that property (unless you do it behind the scenes, but that is a different matter).

However, you can ask the object to change its *own internals*, if it is a mutable object.

If you want to see this in practice, you can use `NSLog` to print the address of the object in question:

```
NSArray *contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"First array"];
NSArray *anotherContentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"Second array"];

[[aClass rootObjectsArrayController] setContent:contentArray];

NSLog(@"Controller address: %p, content array address: %p", [aClass rootObjectsArrayController], [[aClass rootObjectsArrayController] content]);

[[aClass rootObjectsArrayController] setContent:anotherContentArray];

NSLog(@"Controller address: %p, content array address: %p", [aClass rootObjectsArrayController], [[aClass rootObjectsArrayController] content]);
```

What you can see here is that the controller has the same address in both cases, and hence also after it has had its content changed. It is therefore still the same instance.

What has changed, of course, is the address of the content, which is internal to the controller object, and modified by the `setContent:` message.